# Traefik for multiple websites

Tags: docker, web, kubernetes, traefik

I need to setup an environment to host multiple websites (hundreds), each with their own domains and external IP addresses. I was thinking about using Kubernetes, Traefik and Letsencrypt for the SSL certs (in AWS). I have a couple of questions:

1. Is the Traefik\Kubernetes combination suitable?
2. Will I need a load balancer or can Traefik support multiple ingress IPs;

Answer (score 2):

1. Opinion question, opinion answer: Yes. It's not as popular as the [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) but a good solution nonetheless.
2. Generally speaking if you want to support thousands of IPs, you will need an additional load balancer that supports it together with a single ingress controller and also if you either expose your Ingress with a service type [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) or [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).

   However, you could actually have multiple ingress controllers, one per IP address  each with its own [ingressClass](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#between-traefik-and-other-ingress-controller-implementations) option. You'll have to check if your cluster can scale up to thousands of ingress controllers.